# multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table mysql error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new to triggers and am getting "multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table" error.

I have created an AFTER Update and an AFTER Delete which are two separate action time/events so I am not really sure why I would be getting the error.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `new_enrolment` AFTER INSERT ON `mdl_user_enrolments` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO c_master (
ud,
firstname,
lastname,
email,
username,
cid,
course
)
SELECT 
mdl_user.id AS uid, 
mdl_user.firstname, 
mdl_user.lastname, 
mdl_user.email, 
mdl_user.suspended, 
mdl_user.username, 
mdl_enrol.courseid AS cid,
mdl_course.fullname AS course
FROM mdl_user_enrolments INNER JOIN mdl_enrol ON mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid = mdl_enrol.id
 INNER JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_enrol.courseid = mdl_course.id
 INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_enrolments.userid
WHERE userid = NEW.userid;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER `remove_enrolment` AFTER DELETE ON `mdl_user_enrolments` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT mdl_enrol.courseid, 
mdl_user_enrolments.userid, 
mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid
FROM mdl_user_enrolments INNER JOIN mdl_enrol ON mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid = mdl_enrol.id
WHERE mdl_user_enrolments.enrolid = OLD.enrolid

DELETE FROM c_master
WHERE uid = OLD.userid AND mdl_enrol.courseid;
END;
```

Since I am new to all of this I am probably missing something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brian, probably you've been adding and removing the same trigger a few times in your table and you have forgotten to remove it last time before create it again. Get sure you've removed it before create again using

```
DROP TRIGGER [IF EXISTS] [schema_name.]trigger_name
```

and then

```
CREATE TRIGGER ....
```

Documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-trigger.html).