# MySQL trigger set a field in the new row based on a calculation

Tags: mysql

I have a table, `f_gas`:

- `id` - int, auto inc
- `date` - date
- `volume` - int
- `kwh` - int

`kwh` is calculated from the `volume` and some other variables, which I will later place into a different table. So, when I insert a new row with a meter reading (date and volume) I wish for it to run the calculation to determine the actual energy usage (kwh).

*(All this because my energy supplier gives me absolutely nothing in usage data!)*

```
CREATE TRIGGER gas_kwh
 BEFORE INSERT ON f_gas 
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     SET NEW.kwh = (NEW.volume * 2.83 * 39.5 * 1.02264 / 3.6)
 END;
```

I've also tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER gas_kwh 
 BEFORE INSERT ON f_gas 
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.kwh = (NEW.volume * 2.83 * 39.5 * 1.02264 / 3.6);
 END;
```

Both are syntax errors and I am not sure exactly why (the error console is non specific as to where the syntax error lies). I've also tried escaping the field names in backticks to no avail. I'm not exactly new to MySQL but I am new to triggers. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try changing it to `AFTER INSERT`

Comment: Did you bracket the trigger creation statements with `delimiter`?

Comment: @Bojangles if I change it to AFTER I get `updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger`. If I then change it to OLD instead I get the same message but with OLD subbed in for NEW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger's syntax is correct. It is possible that MySQL client cannot parse statements. You need to use DELIMITER command, e.g.:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER gas_kwh
BEFORE INSERT
ON f_gas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.kwh = (NEW.volume * 2.83 * 39.5 * 1.02264 / 3.6);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Article about DELIMITER - [What is the DELIMITER in MySQL and what it’s used for](http://buysql.com/mysql/42-delimiter-mysql.html).

Also, for your trigger you can do this -

```
CREATE TRIGGER gas_kwh
BEFORE INSERT
ON f_gas
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.kwh = (NEW.volume * 2.83 * 39.5 * 1.02264 / 3.6);
```

Comment: None of the delimiter stuff worked, but the last bit did. However, this was only after finding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309322/multiple-triggers-with-the-same-action-time-and-event-for-one-table-mysql-error which suggests that at some point the trigger was saved despite the errors. Odd.

Comment: I can say that DELIMITER it is a client command, find out this command is supported by client in documentation. For example, MySQL command line cliend, [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) support it.